# Как обработать вывод JSON в AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Нужно после запроса вывести ответ, при этом запрос посылается каждую секунду.
Если использовать
$('#team-row').html(`<div>${item.team} команда на ${item.stage} этапе</div>`) эту строку, то он выводит последний элемент.
Нужно вывести все элементы и чтобы они не выводились повторно, как в случае с ****append**.**

```html
function ajaxSend() {
    $.ajax({
        url: './php/response.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $(result).each(function(index, item) {
                 $('#team-row').html(`<div>${item.team} команда на ${item.stage} этапе</div>`)
            })
        }
    });

    
}

setInterval(ajaxSend, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#team-row').html('');
$(result).each(function(index, item) {
  $('#team-row').append(`<div>${item.team} команда на ${item.stage} этапе</div>`);
})
```